# TypeError: jquery__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4___default(...)(...).modal is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, bootstrap-modal, react-bootstrap

I'm developing a ReactJS application where I want to hide a modal after a button on it has been pressed and display another modal accordingly. The id of the first modal is `confirmationModal` and the id of the second modal is `warningModal`. So I'm using the following code in order to achieve the above-mentioned functionality:

```
  $('#confirmationModal').modal('toggle');
  $('#warningModal').modal('toggle');
```

I have tried different approaches but again and again, I end up with the same error.

```
TypeError: jquery__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4___default(...)(...).modal is not a function
```

I checked out other similar questions where they have mentioned that the order in which we specify the scripts of jQuery and Bootstrap should be correct i.e. the jQuery scripts should be declared first and then we should be declaring the Bootstrap script. I have checked the order as well in which I'm declaring the scripts and below is the order:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/popper.js@1.12.6/dist/umd/popper.js" integrity="sha384-fA23ZRQ3G/J53mElWqVJEGJzU0sTs+SvzG8fXVWP+kJQ1lwFAOkcUOysnlKJC33U" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-material-design@4.1.1/dist/js/bootstrap-material-design.js" integrity="sha384-CauSuKpEqAFajSpkdjv3z9t8E7RlpJ1UP0lKM/+NdtSarroVKu069AlsRPKkFBz9" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script>$(document).ready(function() { $('body').bootstrapMaterialDesign(); });</script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-material-design@4.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap-material-design.min.css" integrity="sha384-wXznGJNEXNG1NFsbm0ugrLFMQPWswR3lds2VeinahP8N0zJw9VWSopbjv2x7WCvX" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/e5ef6344ab.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

I couldn't find any mistake in the order of my scripts in which they have been declared so I believe the error would be somewhere else. The scripts that I have mentioned above have been taken from this [Bootstrap Website](https://fezvrasta.github.io/bootstrap-material-design/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/#quick-start) (except for font awesome script which has been obviously taken from [font awesome website](https://fontawesome.com/).)

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks

**PS:** I have also imported the jQuery library in my ReactJS application which as follows: `import $ from 'jquery';`.

Comment: did you also include `import 'bootstrap';` inside component ?

Comment: No, I haven't done that. I have just copied the <script> tag for the Bootstrap library ( given on the Bootstrap Website ) in my index.html file in order to import bootstrap in my project.